# SSIS trying to convert varchar(50) to float from PSA to ODS database

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, datamart

This is a table from our PSA database from a flat file. 
[image: Database table our school gave us]

This is the flat file:
[image: flat file]

We our trying to fill our ODS database with the data from the PSA database. This is the design of the container table from our ODS database:
[image: ods]

We are using a data conversion in visual studio sql server data tools like this:
[image: ssdt]

This is what the data conversion looks like:
[image: data conversion]

The error we are getting is this:

```
[Data Conversion [2]] Error: Data conversion failed while converting column "PricePerKm" (85) to column "Copy of PricePerKm" (30).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
```

Comment: Personally, I avoid doing transformation in SSIS; it's quirky. Have you tried following a ELT method; thus loading your data as is (as a `varchar`) into a staging table and then transforming the data, using T-SQL, into your production table.

Comment: What is the collation / locale setting of your database?   I wonder if the data using commas for a decimal point is confusing it.

Comment: In the same vein what is the locale setting on the flat-file connection manager? See this maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647532/how-to-import-a-flat-file-without-changing-regional-settings-on-the-deployment-s

Comment: First, remove the `$` and `,` from your fields before converting it. second _don't_ use `float`, use `decimal`. Lastly, since you already have the file in a table, don't use SSIS to transform it, use T-SQL

Comment: Yeah, actually. You're using an OLE DB source and not a flat file.

Comment: I used a flat file to load the data in a PSA database and now im trying to load the data into the ODS from the PSA

Comment: Watch out Nick. I had to delete my answer with that same logic in it because of negative feedback

Comment: It's OK I'm used to my advice being ignored on here

Comment: I think your source column length(85) and destination column length(30) are not equal