# SSIS: Date format Issue csv file to a SQL Server table: DD and MM swapped

Tags: sql-server, csv, datetime, ssis, etl

I have a csv file with a Date column with MM/DD/YYYY format. When I load the csv file to a SQL Server table with SSIS, I would like to have the following format: YYYY-MM-DD.

The issue is that when the csv file contain a date with a day value between 1 and 12, the day and the month are swapped.

Example:

```
12/06/2019 in csv file -> 2019-06-12 in SQL Server table: DD and MM are swapped
MM/DD/YYYY  ->  YYYY-MM-DD
```

How could I do to have 2019-12-06 in SQL Server table?

Thanks in advance for yours answers.

Comment: Dates have no format. They are binary values. If you use a date type to store dates, eg `date`,  `datetime` etc, the stored value won't have any format. Formats apply only when strings are parsed into dates or dates are formatted as strings for display

Comment: Are you sure you aren't confusing the format used by your *client* tool (SSMS is just a client tool) for some actual date format? SSMS uses the ISO8601 format to avoid confusion. Other client tools (eg desktop applications) will use the user's locale to format the dates

Comment: What is `12/06/2019` supposed to mean anyway? June 12th (today) or December 6th? If it's June 12th, the CSV dates are in DD/MM, not MM/DD. The culture used to parse dates and numbers in a flat file is controlled by the `LocaleID` setting in the Flat File source. If you want `MM/DD`, change the locale to `en-US`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a flat file without changing regional settings on the deployment server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647532/how-to-import-a-flat-file-without-changing-regional-settings-on-the-deployment-s)

Comment: Are you *sure* the data refers to December 6th? It's far, far more likely that the file contains *today's* records, (June 12th) and there was no reversal. `YYYY-MM-DD` is the ISO8601 format for displaying dates. The order of its components doesn't change

Comment: Have you solved the issue? You didn't accepted or replied to one of the existing answers?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why that shouldn't work.

I took an example:

1. Created a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DateTable](
[TestDat] [datetime] NULL,
[TestDat1] [datetime] NULL,
[TestDat2] [datetime] NULL,
[TestDat3] [datetime] NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
```

2. Created a CSV file with following dates: 
12/06/2019,01/06/2019,02/06/2019,03/06/2019

3. Created an SSIS package with only dataflow. The dataflow task contains a Flat File Source and an OLE DB Destination. 

   The DataFlow task looks like this:
   [image]

   And the mapping in OLE DB Destination looks like this: 
   [image]

After running the SSIS package, I get the following data populated to SQL Server Table.
It is has always taken 06 as Date. 
[image: SQL Table Result]

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue, since when handling MM/dd/yyyy and dd/MM/yyyy date string formats and month and day are less than 12.

Since csv files are text files date are stored as text, implicitly converting these fileds to a datetime filed (sql database) may cause this issue.

Best way to insure that dates are converted correctly is to add a Script component, add a Output column of type `DT_DATE` (exampl: `outDate`) and use `DateTime.ParseExact()` function to force converting using `MM/dd/yyyy` format:

```
Row.outDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.csvDateFiled,"MM/dd/yyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can refer to the following similar question for more details:

- [Importing yyyyMMdd Dates From CSV in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479446/importing-yyyymmdd-dates-from-csv-in-ssis/43479585#43479585)

Comment: You can specify the LocaleID in the flat file source properties.

Comment: Given the *current date* though (June 12th), I suspect the OP confused MM/DD with DD/MM, and the file actually contains records for June 12th, not December 6th

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this may works if the column data type is set to `DT_DATE`

Comment: That's what already happened, for the dates to appear this way. A script component would do the same thing too. Instead of `DateTime.ParseExact` you could use `DateTime.Parse` with the `en-US` culture.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if the column data type is text `DT_STR` or `DT_WSTR` he must validate the date manually (script / derived column)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i agree with that

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the OP now has two options